# Regex for finding the first single slash and last slash

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-group, regexp-replace

This is my url structure.

`abc.com/SOLAPUR_JANATA_SAHKARI_BANK_LTD.SOLAPUR/MAHARASHTRA/index.html`

These types of pattern create problems with mkdir() in php
`SOLAPUR_JANATA_SAHKARI_BANK_LTD.SOLAPUR`
`SOLAPUR_JANATA_SAHKARI_BANK_LTD.SOLAPUR./ (./ considers directory)`

What I want to achieve is
Get content between first single slash and end single slash that is

`SOLAPUR_JANATA_SAHKARI_BANK_LTD.SOLAPUR/MAHARASHTRA`

and replace . with @
`SOLAPUR_JANATA_SAHKARI_BANK_LTD@SOLAPUR/MAHARASHTRA/`

Please suggest regex for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Pleas provide your code for further context and to show the community what you have tried so far. Also, please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Regexes aren't always the answer.  Why not split the string on slashes,  replace the dots in indexes 1+, then join it back together with a slash.

Comment: Yes, it can be done. But I will have other problems for my usecases. That's why I am exploring regex. @TrentonTrama

Answer (score 0):

You can try a match like this:
`^.*?\/(.+)\.(.+\/).*$`

Replace with `\1@\2`

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/i0WM2O/2

Explanation:

- `^.*?\/`: Match the beginning of input and everything up to and including the first `/`. `.*?` is non-greedy (lazy) so it will only match until the first `/`
- `(.+)\.` : Group capturing everything after the first `/` (above) until to the `.`
- `(.+\/)`: Group capturing everything after the `.` up to and including the last `/`. `+` is greedy by default so `.+` will capture any matching `/` until the last one.
- `.*$`: Match whatever is left

The first group captures between the first `/` and the `.`, for example `SOLAPUR_JANATA_SAHKARI_BANK_LTD`

The second group captures between `.` and including the last `/`, so `SOLAPUR/MAHARASHTRA/`

So `\1@\2` results in `SOLAPUR_JANATA_SAHKARI_BANK_LTD@SOLAPUR/MAHARASHTRA/`

Answer (score 0):

that RegExp will work => `\/(.*)\/`

```js
let input = 'abc.com/SOLAPUR_JANATA_SAHKARI_BANK_LTD.SOLAPUR/MAHARASHTRA/index.html';

output = input.replace(/\/(.*)\//, 'foo');

console.log(`output: ${output}`);
```